# Nginx Configure Static Site and Django+uWSGI

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am having a bit of trouble getting Nginx to serve a static index.html page, and also to serve a a Django site. **Could anyone point me out to what I'm doing wrong?**

- I have port `80` and `8000` open.
- I have spent three days trying to get this working.
- Locally I have no problems, then again I'm not using nginx for that.

I placed [**uwsgi_params**](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Nginx.html#what-is-the-uwsgi-params-file) within `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params`

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled**

Here are my symlinks to the actual configuration files

```
site1.conf -> /home/jesse/projects/site1/conf/site1.conf
site2.conf -> /home/jesse/projects/site2/conf/site2.conf
```

**/home/jesse/projects/site1/conf/site1.conf**

This is just a basic **static** site, but it won't load :(

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site1.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://site1.com$1 permanent;


    location / {
       root /home/jesse/projects/site1/;
    }
}
```

**/home/jesse/projects/site2/conf/site2.conf**

= The `manage.py/wsgy.py` is located under `/home/jesse/projects/site2/site2/`

= This is a Django site using **uWSGI**, I installed it with `$ pip install uwsgi`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site2.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://site2com$1 permanent;

    root /home/site2/projects/site2/site2;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/jesse/site2/projects/site2/site2/static/;
        #expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /home/jesse/site2/projects/site2/site2/media/;
        #expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

**/home/site2/projects/site2/conf**

```
[uwsgi]
projectname = site2
projectdomain = site2.com
base = /home/jesse/site2/projects/site2/site2

# Config
plugins = python
master = true
protocol = uwsgi
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=%(projectname).settings
pythonpath = %(base)/src/%(projectname)
module = %(projectname).wsgi
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
logto = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.log

# Runs daemon in background
daemonize = /home/jesse/log/$(projectname).log
```

**Nginx Restart**

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx                                           [ OK ]
```

= The site1 produces a Not Found (Not a 404)

= The site2 produces a

I would appreciate any assistance :)

Comment: ``= The site2 produces a`` - what?

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://site1.com$1 permanent;
```

this in site1, is not managed by any server, because no server_name handles site.com (without www).

then again with site2

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://site2com$1 permanent;
```

first fix those lines.

the correct way in my opinion is to write a server rule that catches www. names and rewrites them to non www, and place site1.com or site2.com as server_name in the rules you have now, as an example of rewiring

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.site1.com
    return 301 http://site1.com$request_uri?;
}
```